# Efficiently updating a table's details?

Tags: c#, database, performance, wcf

What I'm trying to do is retrieve a Patient's details from the database, then based on the values entered in the textboxes, it will update the patient's details, but if the textbox is empty, I assign existing details to the textbox which I think is rather stupid.

What would you suggest I do to improve the code below to make it more efficient or less repetitive?

Code:

```
client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

pat = client.GetPatientbyID(txtUpdatePatientID.Text);
grdView.DataSource = pat;
grdView.DataBind();

if (txtUpdateForename.Text == "")
                txtUpdateForename.Text = pat[0].Forename;
if (txtUpdateSurname.Text == "")
                txtUpdateSurname.Text = pat[0].Surname;
if (txtUpdateStreet.Text == "")
                txtUpdateStreet.Text = pat[0].Street;
if (txtUpdateTown.Text == "")
                txtUpdateTown.Text = pat[0].Town;
if (txtUpdateCity.Text == "")
                txtUpdateCity.Text = pat[0].City;
if (txtUpdateDOB.Text == "")
                txtUpdateDOB.Text = pat[0].DOB.ToString();
if (txtUpdateHouseNumber.Text == "")
                txtUpdateHouseNumber.Text = pat[0].House_number;
if (txtUpdateMobile.Text == "")
                txtUpdateMobile.Text = pat[0].Mobile;

client.UpdateAllDetails(txtUpdatePatientID.Text, txtUpdateForename.Text, 
                        txtUpdateSurname.Text, txtUpdateStreet.Text, txtUpdateTown.Text, 
                        txtUpdateCity.Text, Convert.ToDateTime(txtUpdateDOB.Text),
                        txtUpdateHouseNumber.Text, txtUpdateMobile.Text);
client.Close();

GetPatients(txtUpdatePatientID);
```

Comment: There are things you can do to make this code less repetitive and more maintainable, but if you mean "efficient" in the sense that it will run faster, you're not going to be able to do much to speed up this particular code snippet.

Comment: What could you suggest to make the code less repetitive?

Comment: Something like what Richard suggests, plus extracting `pat[0]` into a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out int he comments, I don't think you can make this much faster; if this is your logic, this is what needs to be done.

You could extract the `if` check and conditional set into a method to tidy up the look of this code maybe?

Something like:

```
private void SetIfNotEmpty(TextBox textBoxToSet, string value)
{
  if (textBoxToSet.Text == "")
    textBoxToSet.Text = value;
}
```

then replace

```
        if (txtUpdateForename.Text == "")
            txtUpdateForename.Text = pat[0].Forename;
        if (txtUpdateSurname.Text == "")
            txtUpdateSurname.Text = pat[0].Surname;
        if (txtUpdateStreet.Text == "")
            txtUpdateStreet.Text = pat[0].Street;
        if (txtUpdateTown.Text == "")
            txtUpdateTown.Text = pat[0].Town;
        if (txtUpdateCity.Text == "")
            txtUpdateCity.Text = pat[0].City;
        if (txtUpdateDOB.Text == "")
            txtUpdateDOB.Text = pat[0].DOB.ToString();
        if (txtUpdateHouseNumber.Text == "")
            txtUpdateHouseNumber.Text = pat[0].House_number;
        if (txtUpdateMobile.Text == "")
            txtUpdateMobile.Text = pat[0].Mobile;
```

with

```
SetIfNotEmpty(txtUpdateForename, pat[0].Forename);
SetIfNotEmpty(txtUpdateSurname.Text, pat[0].Surname);
SetIfNotEmpty(txtUpdateStreet.Text, pat[0].Street);
SetIfNotEmpty(txtUpdateTown.Text, pat[0].Town);
SetIfNotEmpty(txtUpdateCity.Text, pat[0].City);
SetIfNotEmpty(txtUpdateDOB.Text, pat[0].DOB.ToString());
SetIfNotEmpty(txtUpdateHouseNumber.Text, pat[0].House_number);
SetIfNotEmpty(txtUpdateMobile.Text, pat[0].Mobile);
```

As a higher level design point, if these are WPF TextBoxes, have you thought about using databinding?

Comment: Thanks, I think my problem is I over complicate things.

Comment: Never heard of WPF text boxes, could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: Sorry I meant is this a WPF or a WinForms app?